# How to test APNS for adHoc Users?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I'm receiving notification in development mode but when I try to check Push Notification for AdHoc users, The AdHoc users get nothing. I' know, I'm doing something wrong but not able to figure it out. Please Help me to check APNS for AdHoc Users. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed the adhoc app and verified your getting a token? Have you verified your backend is receiving a token? Where is your code so we can review?

Comment: Are you using production SSL certificate for AdHoc? Also you have to use production gateway to send the notifications  i.e. "gateway.push.apple.com" and NOT "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure you install production APN certificates on your server, not development certificates.

After that make sure, you are sending the notification to right server URL

- Sandbox: `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`, port 2195. (for the
  development)
- Production: `gateway.push.apple.com`, port 2195. (for the    release)

Still you have the same problem, try this App. [APN Tester](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apn-tester-free/id626590577?mt=12)

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem too

Answer (score 1):

Below link for complete step to implementation of APNS with creating of certification to test notification utility program called ["PushMeBaby"](https://github.com/stefanhafeneger/PushMeBaby)

[Test Push notification using PushMeBaby](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/programming-apple-push-notification-services)

May this helps lot.